# .net core 2 console application bind datamodel

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0

I have these configuration models:

```
public class AppConfiguration
{
    public string StateFilesPath { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,ActionsSettings> ActionsSettings { get; set; }
}

public class ActionsSettings
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

I have this json:

```
{
  "StateFilesPath": "StateFilesPath...",
  "ConnectionString ": "BIConnectionString...",
  "ActionsSettings": [
    {
      "Reg": {
        "ApiUrl": "ApiUrl...",
        "TableName": "TableName..."

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my `Main` function:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

            configuration = builder.Build();
```

Is it possible to build `AppConfiguration` automatically?
again, this is .net core 2 console application

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this page in the .NET Core documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration#bind-to-an-object-graph I think it has what you're looking form

Comment: @JamieTaylor if you are speaking about the `Bind` function, I think its relevant only for .net core 1. not 2. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `Bind()` method with Core 2:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
var appConfig = new AppConfiguration();
configuration.GetSection("App").Bind(appConfig);
```

But with Core 2, you can also use the `Get<T>()` method which can be more convenient:

```
IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
var appConfig = configuration.GetSection("App").Get<AppConfiguration>();
```

Both are extension methods, so you need the namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
```

Comment: This (the use of `Get<T>`) is what I was going to suggest. It's (kind of) what I'm doing here:https://github.com/GaProgMan/OwaspHeaders.Core/blob/master/example/Startup.cs (it looks to be very similar to what OP wants to do.

Comment: Those are extension methods. You need to add the namespace. See my updated answer.